# Take substring from a string in C

Tags: c, whitespace, substring

I have a string 'Merry Christmas'. I want to separate this one as 'Merry' and 'Christmas'. In Objective c, I could do it easily by `componentsSeparatedByString:` . How to do this in C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to split the string in C.

Answer (score 1):

try to look for [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way in **pure C** is to use [`strtok`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), although it's a rather dangerous and destructive function (it modifies the passed in character buffer).

In **C++**, there are better ways; see here: [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own function.
The C library include `strtok(), strspn() and strcspn()` and what you call a String is an array of char (which end by `\0`).

Answer (score 1):

strtok is the generic solution for string tokenizing. A simpler, more limited way is to use strchr:

```
#include <string.h> // strchr, strcpy
#include <stddef.h> // NULL

const char str[] = "Merry Christmas";
const char* ptr_merry = str;
const char* ptr_christmas;

ptr_christmas = strchr(str, ' ');

if(ptr_christmas != NULL)
{
  ptr_christmas++; // point to the first character after the space
}


// optionally, make hard copies of the strings, if you want to alter them:
char hardcpy_merry[N];
char hardcpy_christmas[n];
strcpy(hardcpy_merry, ptr_merry);
strcpy(hardcpy_christmas, ptr_christmas);
```

Answer (score 0):

For substring use [`strndup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html). For tokenizing/splitting use [`strtok`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html).